# spring data query filter on property not on field

Tags: spring-data

I have a pojo that contains this field:

```
    @Transient
    private EventType eventType;
```

where EventType in an enum:

To persist this field I use the property access:

```
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "EVENT_CODE")
    String getEventTypeCode() {
        return eventType.getEventCode();
    }

    void setEventTypeCode(String eventCode) {
        eventType = EventType.decode(eventCode);
    }
```

I need to filter on that property but with spring data I don't know how to do it.
Is it possible?

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Spring Data Specifications. You use them by calling repository.findAll(s);

Specifications allow you add on arbitrary conditions to your query, including the filter you want to add. See here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications